# Format a number with decimal mark

Tags: elixir

How do I format a number like this:
`95263.51`

to be with decimal mark (comma):
`95.263,51`

or even with decimal point (which is more common):
`95,263.51` ?

Comment: I flagged this question for a moderational attention.

Answer (score 6):

Found the way to do it,
using the [Number](https://hex.pm/packages/number) package:
`iex> Number.Delimit.number_to_delimited(98765432.98, delimiter: ".",separator: ",")
"98 765 432,98"`